# Create iframe on page:

Tags: javascript, iframe

I use iframe method to make a cross-domain request and this is a function code:

```
<script>
    function postIframe(target_url, method, params) 
    {
        //Add iframe
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.style.display = "none";

        //Give the frame a name
        var frame_name = "frame_name" + (new Date).getTime();
        iframe.contentWindow.name = frame_name;

        //build the form
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.target = frame_name;
        form.action = target_url;
        form.method = method;

        //loop through all parameters
        for (var key in params)
        {
            if (params.hasOwnProperty(key))
            {
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "hidden";
                input.name = key;
                input.value = params[key];
                //form.appendChild(input);
            }
        }

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }

    var target_url = 'http://domain.com/test/example.php';
    var method     = 'POST';

    var obj = { var2domain: "ya", var2domainval: "baz" };
    postIframe(target_url, method, obj);
</script>
```

And i get a message in console say: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null", What is my wrong ?!

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain - myself I would recommend JSONP

[What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Looks like your iFrame is not being created. Is this script hosted on client side?

Comment: Yes it is hosted in client side, is this a problem ?

Comment: OK if it is in Client Side then the issue is the function is being called too early - should be called on document.load or $(document).ready. Try it using a button to be sure

Answer (score 0):

you are using a wrong method. even if you solve the exception the code will not work. you will still have cross-domain issue, unless you load the iframe  from the server you need to send the request.  JSONP is an alternate but it wont support POST calls (i hope).